# Python requests, how to avoid DDOSing someone

Tags: python, python-requests

I am writing a plugin for a software I am using. The goal here is to have a button, that will automate downloading data from a government site.

I am still a bit new to python, however I have managed to get it working exactly like I want. But - I want to avoid a case where my plugin makes hundreds of requests for downloads at once, as that could impact the website performance. The below function is what I use to download the files.

How can I make sure that what I am doing will not request 1000s of files within few seconds, thus overloading the website? Is there a way to make the below function wait for completing one download, before starting another?

```
import requests
from os.path import join

def downloadFiles(fileList, outDir):
    # Download list of files, one by one
    for url in fileList:
        file = requests.get(url)
        fileName = url.split('/')[-1]
        open(join(outDir, fileName), 'wb').write(file.content)
```

Comment: Your code will already wait to complete a request before starting an other. If you want to wait a few ms between each request, you can add a `time.sleep(wait_time_in_sec)`  at the end of each loop.

Comment: The requests module is synchronous so you would only send one request after another. If you want to run multiple you would need to work asynchronously for example with aIOHTTP: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/. Then you could eventually DDOS the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is already sequential and it will wait for a download to finish before starting a new one. It's funny, usually people ask how to parallelize stuff.

If you want to slow it down further, you can add a `time.sleep()` to your code.

If you want to be more fancy you can use something like [this](https://github.com/tomasbasham/ratelimit)

Comment: This is great thanks! I was worried this would be difficult haha